# Multiple user input Search

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I want this code to query msqli database base on user multiple filer choice but its not responding for other input fields, what's the error

```
$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select * from products where city like '$find' OR state like '$find' OR location like '$find' AND category like '$sfind'");
```

This is the Header code:

```
<?php


include('includes/config.php');
$find="%{$_POST['place']}%";
$sfind="%{$_POST['type']}%";


?>
```

Multiple Form input

```
<form>

 <!--Keyword-->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group my-2">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="keyword" name="place" placeholder="Address, City or ZIP">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--Type-->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                            <select class="custom-select my-2 border-left" id="type" name="type">
                                <option value="">Type</option>
                                <option value="8">For Sale</option>
                                <option value="7">For Rent</option>
                                <option value="9">Joint Venture</option>
                                <option value="10">Short Let</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to check if you are getting the value from $find or $sfind.
2. If not then you have to use jquery to pass the selected value from dropdown or input